# EmguCV How to create a Mat using an existing Mat?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am new to `EmguCV` and trying to do a simple task; instantiate a `Mat` using an existing one. Here is the code snippet:

```
Mat color = CvInoke.Imread("000.bmp"); //512x512 3 channel image
Mat color2 = new Mat(512, 512, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 3, color.Ptr, 512 * 3);
CvInvoke.Imshow("Color2", color2);
CvInvoke.WaitKey(0);
```

It shows a corrupted image. It seems like the step and channel parameter are not correct. I also tried a gray image (3 changed to 1) with the same result.

Any suggestions that I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

According to [EmguCV Documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.4.0/document/html/c0cc246f-7c2a-e2c9-7b98-f2a98beef077.htm), this command doesn't copy the source `Mat` to the target `Mat`, it only **Create a Mat header from existing data**, also it **does not allocate matrix data. Instead, it just initializes the matrix header that points to the specified data, which means that no data is copied.**

If you want to create a new `Mat` with the date of the old one, you can use this:

```
Mat color2 = new Mat();        
color.CopyTo(color2);
```

Comment: That explains the problem and debugger does show the color2 does not have data. Now I am wondering what the Mat header constructor is used for. In what case, people creates a Mat header but without a body?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea. I searched fot its meaning, but found nothing.